# Deserialize a specified object by a user of a JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows, visual-studio

I have a textbox where the user can enter a number that will retrieve info from a specific movie. I am using Json.NET by Newtonsoft.

I have this:

```
public class Movie
{
   public int number { get; set; }
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string director { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Movie movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\MoviesJSON.json"));

    enteredNumber = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    label7.Text = movie.title[enteredNumber]; <---- //I am not sure about this. But it's kind of what want to get to.
}
```

I want to display the name of the movie(title) given by the enteredNumber.

This is my JSON file:

```
{ 
    "movies": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "title": "Unbroken",
            "director": "Angelina Jolie"
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "title": "Avatar",
            "director": "James Cameron"
        },
        {
            "number": 3,
            "title": "Batman: The Dark Knight",
            "director": "Christopher Nolan"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do the JSON and c# classes look like?  Possibly you should be deserializing a `List<Movie>`, but there's to tell from the code you have provided.

Comment: @dbc: There I've updated it!

Comment: We still need to see an example of the JSON.  Also, what do you mean by *//This where it all goes wrong*?

Comment: @dbc: There I've added the JSON text and changed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your classes, the following helper method will get the movie title at a zero-based index in the JSON movie array, given an index string typed by the user:

```
    public static string GetMovieTitle(string json, string enteredNumberText)
    {
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        try
        {
            var enteredNumber = Int32.Parse(enteredNumberText);
            if (enteredNumber < 0 || enteredNumber >= root.movies.Count)
                return null;
            return root.movies[enteredNumber].title;
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            // Invalid number typed by the user.  Handle if desired.
            throw;
        }
        catch (System.OverflowException)
        {
            // Too large or small number typed by the user.  Handle if desired.
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
label7.Text = movie[enteredNumber].title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your Movie class to make it clear, and exception details if there is.

It seems like your Movie class is something like that:

```
public class Movie
{
   public List<String> title;
   public List<String> director;
   public List<DateTime> year;
   ...
}
```

If so, it should work. (i need to say that, it's a terrible design)